# Logic in component or mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

If MyComponent gets data from the redux store, but organises it in some way first before mapping it, should that organisation be done in the component or mapStateToProps function and why?

```
const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {

  // IN HERE?

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((d) => (...))}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const output = state.data

 // OR HERE?

  return { data: output };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: I'd put it in the selector, that way you can re use it again if the same formatted data is needed for other components. Have a look at reselect to create re usable selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Hello have a nice day.

i think is better have a file with all the logic to conect with redux, so every time i need to connect with redux i create a file that name is ComponentNameContainer.jsx, this file looks like that:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import Row from '../components/Row';
import {doSomething} from '../redux/somethingActions'
// here the imports of function from your actions
export default withRouter(connect(
            (state, ownProps) => {
                return {
                   // props that u need from redux
                   // example: state.sessionReducer.user
                }
            },
            {
             // functions that u need from redux 
             //example: doSomething
            }
        )(Row))
```

i have a folder call containers to store all the container files to keep track of the components that are connected with redux.